# Best way to generate pdf client-side or server side

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, web

I want to create a pdf file with some info generated by the user. This info can be tables, images and text.

My question is, which is the best solution for my problem, is it a server-side solution or client-side?

Note: I am looking for a platform that allow me to do almost everything.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this using GhostScript.  It is a little bit of work to get set up, but once you get it working, it is great.

Comment: I've never tried to generate a PDF on the client, I wouldn't even know where to begin. I'd go with the server side so that you can control it and make sure it is actually created properly before giving it to the client.

Comment: *"which is the best solution for my problem, is it a server-side solution or client-side?"* That's totally up to you. There are client-side solutions for this. There are server-side solutions for this.

Comment: Personally I like FPDF a lot (http://www.fpdf.org/). It's easy and pretty straight forward to use.

Comment: First thanks a lot for the comments, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For server side [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=en) is very versatile.

For client side you can try [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Example(jsPDF):

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```